# Why mathematically can the noise $\epsilon$ of a regression be dropped when computing the density $p(y|x, \theta)$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, linear-regression, noise

In the notes of Andrew Ng on [linear regression p.11-12](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf) it is written the following:

Let us assume that the target variables and the inputs are related via the equation
$$
y^{(i)} = \theta^\top x^{(i)} + \epsilon^{(i)} 
$$
where $\epsilon^{(i)}$ is an error term that captures either unmodeled effects or random noise. We assume that

- $\epsilon^{(i)}$ ie ndenpendently and identically distributed
- $\epsilon^{(i)} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$

i.e. the density of $\epsilon^{(i)}$ is given by
$$
p(e^{(i)}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\Big(-\frac{(\epsilon^{(i)})^2}{2\sigma^2}\Big)\tag{1}
$$
**This implies that**
$$
p(y^{(i)}|x^{(i)}; \theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\Big(-\frac{(y^{(i)}-\theta^\top x^{(i)})^2}{2\sigma^2}\Big)\tag{2}
$$

**My question**

If 
$$
p(e^{(i)}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\Big(-\frac{(\epsilon^{(i)})^2}{2\sigma^2}\Big)
\quad \text {implies that} \quad 
p(y^{(i)}|x^{(i)}; \theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\Big(-\frac{(y^{(i)}-\theta^\top x^{(i)})^2}{2\sigma^2}\Big)
$$
That means that we assume that
$$
y^{(i)} = \theta^\top x^{(i)} + \epsilon^{(i)} \approx \theta^\top x^{(i)}\tag{3}
$$
Or in other words:
$$
p(y^{(i)}|x^{(i)}; \theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\Big(-\frac{(y^{(i)}-(\theta^\top x^{(i)}+ \epsilon^{(i)}))^2}{2\sigma^2}\Big) \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\Big(-\frac{(y^{(i)}-\theta^\top x^{(i)})^2}{2\sigma^2}\Big)\tag{4}
$$

- is ok to infer (3) and (4) from (1) and (2)?
- if yes, How can we mathematically justify (4) using this notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By change of variables. Suppose $X\sim f_X(x)$, where $f_X(.)$ reperesents the probability density function and $F_x(.)$ represents cumulative distribution function, $X$ is the random variable and $x$ is a known, deterministic value (given value). Now you want to compute the density of $Y=X+a$ where $a$ is deterministic, thus 
$F_Y(b)=$Pr$\{Y\le b\}=$Pr$\{X+a\le b\}=$Pr$\{X\le b-a\}=F_X(b-a)$ differentiating both sides yields $f_Y(b)=f_x(b-a)$.

Also notice that if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, then $f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)=f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)$ and if we define $Y_1=X_1+a$ and  $Y_2=X_2+a$ then $F_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)=$Pr$\{Y_1 \le y_1,Y_2 \le y_2\}=$Pr$\{X_1 \le y_1-a,X_2 \le y_2-a\}=$Pr$\{X_1 \le y_1-a\}$Pr$\{X_2 \le y_2-a\}$ which means $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ will be independent also and thus again by differentiation we have $f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)=f_{X_1}(y_1-a)f_{X_2}(y_2-a)$. This can be generalized to arbitrary $n$ variable.

the noise model here is like a memory-less additive white Gaussian channel.

Comment: Thanky for your answer @K.K.McDonald. However, I'm not sure how to relate your answer to my particular question. For this, I reformulated the question. Is it possible to justify (4) by using that same notation?

Comment: Awww, I got it. See, we are not omitting or removing the noise. The effect of noise is that $y^{(i)}$ is random too. If we ignore the noise, then why we consider a distribution for $y^{(i)}$ at first place? 

The noise is still there in $y^{(i)}$, but the reason you can't see the variable $\epsilon^{(i)}$ is that it is replaced via this $\epsilon^{(i)}= y^{(i)} - \theta^\top x^{(i)}$. Similar to my answer, the density of $Y$ becomes $f_X(b-a)$, where did $y$ go? it is replaced. We can think of it as this: if $\epsilon^{(i)}$ has given density, what will the density of $y^{(i)}$ be?

Comment: Yeah indeed I figured that out in the meantime too... many thanks for your help!